# pyqtgraph: simplest way to pause ipython script until user has placed a roi object

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook, pyqtgraph

I would like to implement the following sequence in a script and keep it as simple as possible (i.e., if possible avoid explicit multi-threading):

1. Process some data. The result is a 2d numpy array, say `a`
2. Show `a` using `pw = pg.show(a)` (after `import pyqtgraph as qt` and using pyqt5)
3. Define a circular roi, e.g. via

`circ = pg.CircleROI([1024,1024],300)
pw.addItem(circ)`

4. The user moves the roi to the relevant place
5. Read out the roi coordinates, continue with the script (where the roi coordinates are used)

My question is: How can I define a break in the script between 3. and 5. such that the user has time to do 4., in a way that the pyqtgraph is not blocked? Ideally, the user would confirm the correct roi position by pressing enter or clicking a button.

Edit: The script is executed in IPython with qt gui.

Edit2: Here is a full test script to be executed in IPython. What I want is that the user can move the circle before the roi is evaluated, i.e., that the print output is something different than `(slice(1024, 1174, None), slice(1024, 1174, None))`

```
import numpy as np
import pyqtgraph as pg

a = np.array(range(2048**2)).reshape((2048,2048))
pw = pg.show(a)
circ = pg.CircleROI([1024,1024],300)
pw.addItem(circ)



roi = np.s_[int(circ.pos().x()):int(circ.pos().x()+circ.size().x()/2),\
            int(circ.pos().y()):int(circ.pos().y()+circ.size().x()/2)]

print(roi)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## 1. raw_input('') in an IPython console

If the script is running in an IPython console, you could try adding a

```
raw_input("Press Enter to continue...")
```

or `input()` in python3 to pause the script. The user has to go back and press enter in the ipython console but the code is simple.

```
import numpy as np
import pyqtgraph as pg

a = np.array(range(2048**2)).reshape((2048,2048))
pw = pg.show(a)
circ = pg.CircleROI([1024,1024],300)
pw.addItem(circ)

raw_input("Press Enter to continue...")

roi = np.s_[int(circ.pos().x()):int(circ.pos().x()+circ.size().x()/2),\
            int(circ.pos().y()):int(circ.pos().y()+circ.size().x()/2)]

print(roi)
```

## 2. Monkey patching keyPressEvent

Another solution could be to monkey patch the keyPressEvent in the ImageWindow.

Beware that this solution uses both **globals** and **monkey patching**, please make sure you know what this means.

```
import numpy as np
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import pyqtgraph as pg


a = np.array(range(2048**2)).reshape((2048,2048))
pw = pg.show(a)
circ = pg.CircleROI([1024,1024],300)
pw.addItem(circ)

def myKeyPressEvent(e):
    if e.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Enter or e.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Return:
        global selectionFinished
        selectionFinished = True

# Monkey patch
selectionFinished = False
pw.keyPressEvent = myKeyPressEvent

while not selectionFinished:
    QtGui.QApplication.processEvents()

roi = np.s_[int(circ.pos().x()):int(circ.pos().x()+circ.size().x()/2),\
            int(circ.pos().y()):int(circ.pos().y()+circ.size().x()/2)]

print(roi)
```

Comment: That was also my first thought. However, the `raw_input` command also freezes the GUI. It wouldn't even open the figure before I press enter If I open the figure manually (i.e., execute all the lines before the `raw_input`), then at the moment I execute the `raw_input` line I cannot move the circle in the figure anymore.

Comment: It ran fine through my ipython console. I put the script in test.py and then ran `import test` in ipython

Comment: True, it does run in standalone ipython but not in my spyder IDE where I initially tested it. In the standalone version, however, I can't close the figure after running this code. Anyways, the second solution works perfectly, it's exactly what I needed!